# What can be the Trace of given Matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $S = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x = \text{Trace(A) for some } A \in M_{4}(\mathbb{R})\}$ such that
$A^3 = I , A \ne I$

then which among the following is true for set $S$

1. $S$ consists of non zero elements
2. Cardinality of $S$ is $4$
3. Cardinality of $S$ is $5$
4. Cardinality of $S$ is infinite .

Here is my approach,

The given matrix satisfies the equation $x^3 -1 =0$

Minimal polynomial divides the given polynomial so,

$m_{A}(x)  | (x^3 -1)$

So, $m_A(x) = (x - 1), (x^2+ x + 1) or(x^3 -1)$

$(x -1)$ is not possible as the matrix is not identity .

So, Minimal polynomial  = $(x^2 + x +1)$ or $x^3 -1$

In first case the possible Eigen Values are:

$ \omega , \omega^2,\omega , \omega^2$, So Trace $A = -2$

In second possible eigen values are $1, 1 , \omega ,\omega^2$ so Trace $A = 1$

So, I think option (1) is the only correct choice .

Can someone please verify my solution and tell my errors ?

Thank you.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: Ah yes, that is a typo the letter $R$ means the same as $\mathbb{R}$ the set of reals.